Bash: Possible to do something before sending script to background?
In a bash script, if a user sends a running script to the background with CTRL+Z, is it possible to do some work before the system takes the script to the background?
I know it's possible to do work on EXIT signals (and others) for example, with trap.
For example:
#!/bin/bash

trap foo SIGINT SIGTERM SIGHUP SIGQUIT
trap bar SIGSTOP

foo() {
  echo "Interrupted"
  # do other cleanup, etc
}

bar() {
  # do stuff first
  echo "Sending to background..."
}

sleep 30

But why doesn't that work?
Desired:
$ bash example.sh 
^CInterrupted

$ bash example.sh 
^Z
Sending to background...
[1]+  Stopped                 bash example.sh

Actual output:
$ bash example.sh 
^CInterrupted

$ bash example.sh 
^Z
[1]+  Stopped                 bash example.sh

And if this effects any answers, OS is Debian/Ubuntu.

SIGSTOP cannot be caught no matter the language. But CTRL+Z sends SIGTSTP, not SIGSTOP, and it can be caught and handled in a Bash script like this:
trap tstp_handler TSTP

tstp_handler() {
  # do stuff first
  echo Sending to background...
  kill -STOP 0
}

sleep 30 &
until wait $!; do
  rc=$?
  if test $rc -le 128 || test $(kill -l $rc) != TSTP; then
    exit $rc
  fi
done


Thanks for the answer. Could you please explain a little more about how all this works/what's going on?

@algalg What exactly do you not understand?

Why are you sending the sleep line to the background and then have the until block with the wait and the if block with tests, etc. Is it not possible to trap the whole script without sending specific lines in it to the background? i.e. I'd like to trap the whole run time, not just specific parts of the bash script, if that make sense?

Also why do you have kill -STOP 0 in tstp_handler()?

@algalg Once you set a trap for TSTP, CTRL+Z no longer stops your script, you need to stop it manually after handling the signal. The commands your script runs won't inherit the trap set for TSTP though, so CTRL+Z still stops them. But since they are run on the foreground and the shell has no job control, it silently waits for them to exit so that the trap can be run. And if you enable job control, TSTP will stop individual commands and your script will ignore it. The only way I know around all this is running the commands at the background and waiting for signals in a loop on the foreground.
